# attempt to index nil with 'Name' error in roblox (lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

Hello please help me with this script
I am trying to make an egg hatching system using alvinblox's tutorial

it says "attempt to index nil with 'Name'" and here is the script
The error is at line 8

```
local camera = workspace.Camera
local studio = workspace.Studio
local template = script.Parent.Pets.ScrollingFrame.Template
local scrollingFrame = script.Parent.Pets.ScrollingFrame

local function addToFrame(pet)
    local newTemplate = template:Clone()
    newTemplate.Name = pet.Name
    newTemplate.petName.Text = pet.Name
    newTemplate.Parent = scrollingFrame
    newTemplate.Visible = true
    local camera = Instance.new("Camera")
    local newPet = pet:Clone()
    newPet.Parent = newTemplate.ViewportFrame
    camera.CFrame = CFrame.new(newPet.PrimaryPart.Position + (newPet.PrimaryPart.CFrame.LookVector * 3), newPet.PrimaryPart.Position)
    camera.Parent = newTemplate.ViewportFrame
    newTemplate.ViewportFrame.CurrentCamera = camera
end

game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg.OnClientEvent:Connect(function (pet)
    addToFrame(pet)
    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    camera.CFrame = studio.CameraPart.CFrame
    wait(1.5)
    for i = 1,50,1 do
        studio["Egg Mesh"].Size = studio["Egg Mesh"].Size + Vector3.new(0.1,0.1,0.1)
        wait(0.01)
    end
    local explosion = Instance.new("Explosion")
    explosion.BlastRadius = 10
    explosion.BlastPressure = 0
    explosion.Position = studio["Egg Mesh"].Position
    explosion.ExplosionType = Enum.ExplosionType.NoCraters
    explosion.DestroyJointRadiusPercent = 0
    explosion.Parent = studio["Egg Mesh"]
    studio["Egg Mesh"].Transparency = 1
    local petClone = pet:Clone()
    for i,v in pairs(petClone:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("ParticleEmitter") then
            v.Enabled = true
        end
    end 
    petClone:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(studio["Egg Mesh"].Position, studio.CameraPart.Position))
    petClone.Parent = studio
    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
        2,
        Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce,
        Enum.EasingStyle.Out,
        0,
        false,
        0
    )
    local tween  = game:GetService("TweenService"):Create(camera, TweenInfo, {CFrame = CFrame.new(petClone.PrimaryPart.Positon + (petClone.PrimaryPart.CFrame.lookVector * 5)+Vector3.new(0,0.75,0)),petClone.PrimaryPart.Position})
    tween:Play()
    wait(5)
    for i,v in pairs(petClone:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("ParticleEmitter") then
            v.Enabled = false
        end
    end 
    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
    studio["Egg Mesh"].Transparency = 0
    studio["Egg Mesh"].Size = Vector3.new(4.7312, 6, 4.732)
end)
```

please let me know if you can help me with this error this is pretty stressful
The fire client code is here:

```
local cost = 50
local petMoudle = require(game.ServerScriptService.BasicEggModule)
local prompt = workspace["Egg Holder"].Part.ProximityPrompt


prompt.Triggered:Connect(function (player)
    if player.leaderstats.Cash.Value >= cost then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - cost
        local pet = petMoudle.chooseRandomPet()
        print(pet.Name.." selected")
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player)
    end
end)
```

The module script is here

```
local petMoudle = {}


petMoudle.Pets = {
    ["Legendary"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets["lil' demon"];
    };
    ["Rare"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets["Ice golem"];
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets["Light Bat"];
    };
    ["Uncommon"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets.Fox
    };
    ["Common"] = {
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets.Bunny;
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchablePets.Mouse
    }
    
}   

petMoudle.rarities = {
    ["Legendary"] = 5;
    ["Rare"] = 15;
    ["Uncommon"] = 30;
    ["Common"] = 50
}

petMoudle.chooseRandomPet = function()
    local randomNumber = math.random(1, 100)
    local counter = 0
    for rarity, weight in pairs(petMoudle.rarities) do
        counter = counter + weight
        if randomNumber <= counter then
            local rarityTable = petMoudle.Pets[rarity]
            local chosenPet = rarityTable[math.random(1, #rarityTable)]
            
            return chosenPet
        end
    end
end
```

return petMoudle

Comment: it is saying that 'pet' is null

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, we don't have enough info to suggest a fix. You need to find the code that is calling `game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient`. It is supposed to tell the client what pet to hatch, but you're not providing that information. If you update your question with that code, we could help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused because `pet` is nil in the expression `pet.Name` on line 8.

As you can see, the value `pet` is provided by the function, `addToFrame(pet)`. It's called on line 21 in the function passed to `game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg.OnClientEvent:Connect`, which gets the argument from the server through the remote event.

If we look in the server script, we can see where that event is fired by the server. The line `game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player)` is called, but it forgets to provide the argument the client is expecting:

```
...
local pet = petMoudle.chooseRandomPet()
print(pet.Name.." selected")
game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player)
```

It should instead be `game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player, pet)`.